# Which of the following extensions are normal?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I want to understand, how to deal with following task:

*Which of the following extensions are normal?*

1. $\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt[6]{3}) / \mathbb{Q}$;
2. $\mathbb{C}(t) / \mathbb{C}\left(t^4\right)$;
3. $\mathbb{R}(t) / \mathbb{R}\left(t^4\right)$;

The first one is pretty obvious, if i am right. I know, that extension is finite and normal iff it is splitting field for some polynomial. In first example polynomial is $x^6+3$, and it is easy to calculate, that every other root of that polynomial is algebraic over  $\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt[6]{3})$. It means that $\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt[6]{3}) / \mathbb{Q}$ is splitting field, i.e. extension is normal.

But i don't know how to approach 2nd and 3rd cases. I think that both extensions are finite, but i can't think of some polynomials like i did in 1st example. Can i use an exact same logic or i need something different?

Upd: as @RobertShore mentioned i didn't wrote proof of first example correct. I meant, that every other root  of $x^6+3$ is **contained** in $\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt[6]{3})$, which leads us to $\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt[6]{3}) / \mathbb{Q}$ being normal, as it is splitting field for  $x^6+3$.

Comment: I think you don't quite understand normality.  You don't just need to show that every other root of $x^6+3$ is algebraic of $\Bbb Q(i \sqrt[6]{3})$, which I'll define as $F$.  That's always true.  You need to show that each other root of $x^6+3$ is actually contained in $F$.  For example, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{3})$ is not normal over $\Bbb Q$ because it doesn't contain any of the roots of $x^6-3$ that aren't real, yet those other roots are definitely algebraic over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{3})$.

Comment: @RobertShore, thanks for correction. I really wanted to say that $\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt[6]{3})$ contains other roots of $x^6+3$. I will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of $t$ in $\Bbb C(t^4)$ or in $\Bbb R(t^4)$ is simply $p(x)=x^4-t^4$.  Moreover, the roots of $p(x)$ (in a suitable algebraic extension) are simply $\pm t, \pm it$.

This tells you that $\Bbb C(t)$ is normal over $\Bbb C(t^4)$, but since $i \notin \Bbb R(t^4)$, we also find that $\Bbb R(t)$ is *not* normal over $\Bbb R(t^4)$.

And yes, since $(i \sqrt[6]{3})^3=-i\sqrt 3$, you are correct that the sixth roots of unity are in $\Bbb Q(i \sqrt[6]{3})$ and that field is normal over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Oh, i see. I missed that part, that the minimal polynomial is $x^4-t^4$. Thanks a lot!